# Petapoco and parameters

Tags: c#, petapoco

Is there a way to use parameters for Insert queries? I get the following error when I try.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set active survey
    /// </summary>
    public int SetSurveyActive(int brandId, int surveyId)
    {
        Sql sql = new Sql()
            .Append("INSERT INTO CF.ActiveSurvey(BrandId, SurveyId")
            .Append("VALUES(@0,@1)",brandId,surveyId);

        var result = database.Execute(sql);

        return Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: wow that seems to be a place of sql injection.

Comment: that's why I'm using parameters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a bracket:

```
.Append("INSERT INTO CF.ActiveSurvey(BrandId, SurveyId")
```

should be

```
.Append("INSERT INTO CF.ActiveSurvey(BrandId, SurveyId)")
```